# Figuring out physical cache layout in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, hardware, cpu, cache

I'm trying to figure out they physical cache layout of my CPU in FreeBSD 10.

I see the following from

```
sysctl kern.sched.topology_spec

kern.sched.topology_spec: <groups>
 <group level="1" cache-level="0">
  <cpu count="4" mask="f">0, 1, 2, 3</cpu>
  <children>
   <group level="2" cache-level="2">
    <cpu count="4" mask="f">0, 1, 2, 3</cpu>
   </group>
  </children>
 </group>
</groups>
```

However, I know that this doesn't match the datasheet for my CPU and dmidecode shows that it is unified L2 as well.

Is there anywhere else that might be worth looking? Or, if the datasheet is incorrect, how could I verify this?

This is for an [Intel® Xeon® Processor E5320](http://ark.intel.com/products/28031/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5320-%288M-Cache-1_86-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB%29). From third party websites, this processor should have 2MB per core of L2 cache which is not what is being reported.

Comment: Might help to specify the whole output of the sysctl and how it differs from what you expect.

Comment: @SteveWills All of `sysctl -a` or just `kern.sched.topology_spec`?

Comment: Just the kern.sched.topology_spec, but the whole thing. And what about it isn't matching?

Comment: @SteveWills done!